# Iterate over the files from a sftp location and pick the latest received file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, pysftp

For example, my filename present in the sftp location is as follows:

1. `AG_DMW_2021052003_5150236`
2. `AG_DMW_2021051903_5150236`
3. `AG_DMW_2021051803_5150236`
4. `AG_DMW_2021051703_5150236`

I need to pick only the File #1 using the python code from the location.
I'm new to python, someone help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

Break it down into easier completable steps.

1. Connect to the SFTP.
2. List files.
3. Extract date from filename
4. Get the newest based on #3
5. Return filename (or download)

I suggest to use [Paramiko](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html) to connect to the SFTP. Go through the documentation to see how to connect and how to list the files, and if needed, how to download with it.

As for #3 & #4, see the code below

```py
from datetime import datetime

listofnames = [
    "AG_DMW_2021052003_5150236",
    "AG_DMW_2021051903_5150236",
    "AG_DMW_2021051803_5150236",
    "AG_DMW_2021051703_5150236",
]


def get_date(string: str):
    # get the date part as a string
    spl = string.split("_")[2][0:8]
    # convert to datetime object
    return datetime.strptime(spl, "%Y%m%d")


# set initial values
last = None
today = datetime.today()
# set the initial last
last = listofnames[0]
for name in listofnames[1:]:
    # you can substract dates and get the day count.
    # the one with the lowest day count is the latest
    if (today - get_date(name)).days < (today - get_date(last)).days:
        last = name

print(last)
```

**output**

```
AG_DMW_2021052003_5150236
```